How many Moldovans in Russia were able to vote in 2016 vs 2024?
Russia claims the recent elections in Moldova are illegitimate, because the Moldovan diaspora in Russia wasn't able to vote as much as they'd have liked.
But looking at the 2016 election, which was won by a pro-Russian candidate, the situation with the diaspora not getting enough ballots was somewhat similar (in a mirror kind of way) then, with precincts in Western countries running out of ballots then.
So, how many Moldovans were able to vote in Russia in 2016 vs 2024?
I'm interested in the actual number of Moldovan voters that cast their votes in Russia in those two years. I'm aware that Moscow has claimed that the number of polling stations (for Moldovans) in Russia was reduced from 20 to 2, but it's unclear to me how many Moldovan voters cast their votes in Russia, in those two elections.
